# How do I run COPY in the gradle EXECUTION step instead of CONFIGURATION step?

Tags: gradle

I have the following task. When I try to put `from/into` into a `doLast` block, gradle skips execution because of "NO SOURCE" status. What am I doing wrong?

```
task extractTerraformBinary (type: Copy) {
    new URL(artifactoryPath).withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
    doLast {
        from zipTree(f.absolutePath).matching { include 'terraform' }.singleFile
        into out
    }

    doLast {
        project.logger.lifecycle(">> Deleting terraform.zip")
        project.delete "${tfFilePath}/terraform.zip"
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
> Task extractTerraformBinary NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':terraform-provider-inops:extractTerraformBinary' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:terraform-provider-inops:extractTerraformBinary (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
```

Version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NO-SOURCE** status happens when a **task is being executed**, but it **hasn't been configured yet**.

In your case you need to remove the *from* and *into* (configuration code) from the *doLast* block and place it to the configuration section, i.e.:

```
task extractTerraformBinary (type: Copy) {
  ...
  from zipTree(f.absolutePath).matching { include 'terraform' }.singleFile
  into out
  ...
}
```

Your task will be then **configured at the configuration time** and the execution should work as expected.